# String replacement inside json not working with complex objects

Tags: karate

I have this Javascript object:

```
{ person: { name: "john", age: 32 }}
```

And an endpoint returning:

```
{
  "name": "john",
  "age": 32
}
```

I have this steps:

```
Given path 'endpoint/'
When method get
Then status 200
And match response ==
"""
{
  "name": #(person.name),
  "age": #(person.age)
}
"""
```

This is not working because #(person.name) and #(person.age) both evaluate to null, how can I fix it? (putting them in a new variable is not the fix I'm looking for)

Comment: PUT THEM IN A NEW VARIABLE :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
* def data = { person: { name: 'john', age: 32 } }
* def response = { name: 'john', age: 32 }
* match response == data.person
```

Since you appear to be confused, let me add this (but not recommended because of the above):

```
* match response == { name: '#(data.person.name)', age: '#(data.person.age)' }
```